# Anaconda is not opening after I upgraded my python version from 3.5 to 3.6

Tags: python, anaconda

Can someone please help me in getting rid of this error?

This is the Error it is showing when I typed `jupyter-notebook` in my terminal, after I upgraded my python 3.5 to 3.6 using the command :
`conda install python=3.6`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
from notebook.notebookapp import main

     File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 45, in <module>
     ioloop.install()

     File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 210, in install
assert (not ioloop.IOLoop.initialized()) or \

     AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'initialized'
```